# Sending email from controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

How make a sending email from controller? I have email address in database, so I get this email from base and send special text message to this email. I don't need use a View.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here we go:

Your code:

```
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();

message.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("yourname@yourdomain.com");
message.To.Add(new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("receiver@receiverdomain.com"));

message.IsBodyHtml = true;
message.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
message.Subject = "subject";
message.Body = "hello receiver";

System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
client.Send(message);
```

And your web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.net>  
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="yourname@yourdomain.com" deliveryMethod="Network">
        <network host="smtp.yourprovider.com" port="587" userName="yourname@yourdomain.com" password="yourpass" enableSsl="true" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
 ...
```

Comment: I have with this two problems: 

1. I havent Encoding. 

2. I have error: `The SMTP host was not specified.`

I working on localhost, I make host with: "smpt.gmail.com" and "localhost:5947"

Answer (score 4):

You could use [MvcMailer](https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/wiki/MvcMailer-Step-by-Step-Guide). Or if you want to implement it manually you could use the [SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) class to send emails.